# Modal Bootstrap 4: Como chamar outro dentro de um modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Galera... eu tenho um modal de cadastro. Sendo que eu gostaria de chamar outro modal, estando ainda dentro dele. Ou seja... Ficaria sobreposto ao meu modal de cadastro.

Estou usando o codigo para chamar o meu modal em Bootstrap 4:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secundary my-2 my-sm-0" id="iniciaCadastro" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cadastraModal">Cadastre-se</button>
```

A estrutura é semelhante a que temos na documentação bootstrap. Usando o Header, Body e footer.

No footer, eu tento chamar um outro modal, com detalhes de termos e condições.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termosModal">Termos de uso</a>
```

Mas, me parece que o bootstrap não suporta essa estratégia...

Alguém pode me ajudar a solucionar esse problema?

Comment: O Bootstrap não suporta modals aninhados. Como dito na [documentação](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/): _"Bootstrap only supports one modal window at a time. Nested modals aren’t supported as we believe them to be poor user experiences."_

Comment: Em termos de UX eu acho isso um grande erro, por isso talvez seria melhor avaliar com o usuário ou com o time de Ux uma forma melhor de apresentação do fluxo desse sistema que você está desenvolvendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue uma solução.

```js
$("#modal").click(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});

$("#modal2").click(function() {
  $('#myModal2').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button" id="modal" class="btn btn-default">Abrir modal</button>


<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="modal2" class="btn btn-success">Abrir modal 2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="myModal2">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading 2</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show! Vou tentar essa solução! :)

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é da forma que imagina, mas a única que existe é utilizando o método $(elemento).modal('show'), você estará sobrepondo modais.

Ficaria da seguinte forma:

Botão abrirá o primeiro modal da forma comum:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

No segundo modal, você vai colocar uma classe no botão que você quer utilizar para abrir o próximo modal:

```
...
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary openModal">Save changes</button>
</div>
...
```

Agora você vai abrir o modal via JavaScript com a própria API dos modais do Bootstrap:

```
$('.openModal').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#exampleModal2').modal('show');
});
```

Sendo que nesse caso, o id do meu outro modal é ***exampleModal2***

Answer (score -1):

olá estava com mesmo problema. Porem descobri que o modal do BOOTSTRAP ele abre com forme a ordem que foi criado no html. ex: se a div do modal2 for criada primeiro que a do modal1 e no modal1 tentar chamar o modal2 ela vai ficar por trás.  Porem se chamar no modal2 o modal1 o modal1 fica na frente

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).